# how to make different user application out of same source code

Tags: android

i have made an android application that retrieves data from internet and performs further operation on that data.

i have 4 urls for retrieving data. so i want to make 4 different applications for 4 different urls, each application receiving data from one of the URL. and i also want to run all four application on the single device.

now my problem is that when i uninstall one of the application all four application gets uninstall, and all the applications are showing the same data.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this. Suggest you look into [Android library projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject).

Comment: hi thanks for reply. but is there any alternative way to do this task.

Comment: You could create and maintain 4 copies of your source code. What's the problem with using a library?